# How to make this 3D photo wall effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, 3d

How can I create a photo wall effect similar to this with Photoshop CS6?

[image]

I tried with `Warp`, but it looks so bad and it's nowhere near comparsion. I also tried with `Edit->Transform->Perspective`, but then it looked more like [this](http://chromespot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/hulu.jpg) and not what I wanted.

I'm also trying it on a smaller image (800x415) and I have lots of thumbnails similar to the ones in the original hulu image, but I merged them into one big image with the idea that it'll be easier.

Comment: Relevant: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/30045/8845

Answer (score 9):

You could also do it like this.

---

So I have bunch of layers that form the grid of images.

[image]

[image]

To give it flexibility, I put them into a Smart Object

[image]

Then from the top menu `Edit > Free Transform` ( ...or Windows: <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> Mac: <kbd>Cmd+T</kbd> )

In the Free Transform toolbar at the top, click Warp modes icon

[image]

On the left side, from the warp dropdown, select Bulge.

[image]

Add minus value to the bend, and you're pretty much done.

Make sure the orientation is correct, by clicking the Warp orientation icon on the left side of Bend. 
[image]

...at this point it looks like this
[image]

You can also add horizontal distortion, if you want to.

[image]

Comment: Derp, I did not know the warp modes were available. Nice one

Comment: +1 for using a Smart Object in your process explanation - it's a really flexible and non-destructive Photoshop method, love it. :)

Answer (score 8):

Joonas's answer is on the money, but another method is to use `Distort > Displace`:

The input is another `.psd` that acts as a displacement map. The red channel controls horizontal distortion, and green controls vertical. Neutral gray means no movement, white = up/left, black = down/right. By setting a couple of gradients across the channels you can get pretty close:

Input Displacement map:

[image]

Input Grid:

[image: Grid]

Output:

[image]

If you're willing to use Imagemagick, I recommend it. [As in this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30045/creating-a-curved-image-photo-wall-montage-using-the-linux-commandline/30063#30063), it has a cylindrical distortion that matches what you need perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

The warp is the only way you're going to get this effect. `Edit -> Transform -> Warp` on the image layer.

For example starting with this:

[image: start]

You can end up with a result like the following, using only the warp tool, you just need to get the wrap points right. Also you might need to add a dark shadow in the centre at the bend.

[image: finish]