# How to design something like this without spaces between layers in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

please, I have tried to design like this picture

[image]

I use CS6 but in my design spaces exit between layers ( squares ) like this

[image]

so please what are my mistakes? and how can I remove spaces between layres ( squares)?

and many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome, migha. You start to build an equilateral triangle. Rotate it 90º. I think now you will figure it out.

Comment: thanks LeoNas for help. how can I measure? to make it equilateral?

Comment: which tool helps me to make it equilateral please?

Comment: Hey migha, we are happy to help designers when they get stuck on a question. However, we are not a tutorial-on-demand site. The solution to this problem is pretty easily found on the internet. Please try to find a tutorial first. If you encounter a specific problem, we will gladly assist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a tutorial-on-demand site. The solution to this problem is pretty easily found on the internet. Please try to find a tutorial first. If you encounter a specific problem, we will gladly assist.

Comment: hi PieBie. thanks for reply. I already know what you are talking about. I have searched internet for solution but have not found any. my specific problem I already cleared on the title of my question is how to remove spaces between theses shapes on my design. so please if it was pretty easy for you, just tell me about the tool that I should use to remove the spaces or make measures more accurate and better

Comment: @PieBie I also found this question https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30469/how-to-make-this-3d-photo-wall-effect-in-photoshop  is pretty like my question but it is not closed

Comment: One more tip: Use the Polygon tool and set the sides to 3. Drag to draw and hold Shift to constrain rotation.

Comment: More easily completed in a vector application (Illustrator, Inkscape) -- draw one shape.. divide it, as opposed to overlapping and aligning separate shapes.

Comment: @migha, that question is nothing like yours, at all. That's a complex perspective skew combined with a gradient to create the illusion of depth. Yours is just how to create an equilateral triangle and place them next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to make an equilateral triangle:

Use the Polygon tool and set the sides to 3.

Drag to draw and hold Shift to constrain rotation.

Now you can duplicate it and change its color.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make overlapping shapes to different layers. It makes no harm if the underlying shape is bigger than another shape above it. The benefit: No need for exactly fitting equilateral triangles, everything can be drawn manually.

In addition, if you had exactly fitting triangles, you would soon ask "how do I make the seams watertight, the black background is still seen through as about 1 px wide line".

Antialiasing would cause it.

Here's an example. A piece of your image has been used as model:

[image]

This is anything but advanced. A black background layer was made at first. The next layer got a green filled hexagon with polygon tool to get some regularity as the beginning. It's a filled area, not a vector shape.

The next layer was a copy of a half of the hexagon; the selection was made with the polygonal lasso tool then copied and pasted in place. A new layer was generated automatically. The selection was painted with different green.

The next layer was a third of the half hexagon - first selecting the hexagon and then drawing a subtracting (=Alt) selection with the polygonal lasso tool diagonally over the the original hexagon.The generated triangular selection was filled with blue in a new layer. The same triangle was duplicated twice and one was flipped horizontally. Now there was enough different parts in different layers to be duplicated and recolored again. Recolorings were made with the paint bucket.

Finally all parts were moved together manually, merged, one outer edge was sliced a little to make it straight. The shape was skewed a little (Edit > Transform). There's no black in the seams because there was in the bottom the green hexagon.

As others have already said, using vector tools, even Illustrator, would be perfect for geometric shape projects like this. But it could be done also with selections in a raster image. Only the first piece, the hexagon has been drawn with a vector like tool.